# Unknown JavaScript Reference Error For A Date & Time Project

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, time

I'm writing a shortcut JavaScript file to make `$date` and `$time` variables. It should work as far as I can tell, but it won't display and Google Chrome's debugger shows a `[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read 'firstChild' of null]`

Here's my code:

```
function mdy(){

    var
        h = new Date(),
        year = h.getFullYear(),
        month = h.getMonth() + 1,
        day = h.getDate();

        if(month < 10) { month = "0" + month; }

        if(day < 10) { month = "0" + month; }

        var string = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

        document.getElementById('mdy').firstChild.nodeValue = string;

}

function ymd(){

    var
        h = new Date(),
        year = h.getFullYear(),
        month = h.getMonth() + 1,
        day = h.getDate();

        if(month < 10) { month = "0" + month; }

        if(day < 10) { month = "0" + month; }

        var string = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;

        document.getElementById('ymd').firstChild.nodeValue = string;

}

var $date = {

    mdy: '<span id="mdy">&nbsp;</span>',
    ymd: '<span id="ymd">&nbsp;</span>'

}

/* $time module */
// this comes in two formats, standard and military. 
// type $time.standard for standard time and $time.military
// for military time
function tstandard(){

    var
        h = new Date(),
        hours = h.getHours(),
        minutes = h.getMinutes();

        minutes = ( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes;

        var diem = ( hours < 12 ) ? "am" : "pm";

        hours = ( hours > 12 ) ? hours - 12 : hours;

        hours = ( hours == 0 ) ? 12 : hours;

        var string = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + diem;

        document.getElementById("tstandard").firstChild.nodeValue = string;

}

function tmilitary() {

    var
        h = new Date(),
        hours = h.getHours(),
        minutes = h.getMinutes();

        minutes = ( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes;

        hours = ( hours == 0 ) ? 12 : hours;

        if(hours < 10) { hours = "0" + hours }

        var string = hours + ":" + minutes;

        document.getElementById("tmilitary").firstChild.nodeValue = string;

}

var $time = {

    standard: "<span id='tstandard'>&nbsp;</span>",
    military: "<span id='tmilitary'>&nbsp;</span>"

}

/*! universal body onload function !*/
window.onload = function(){

    mdy(); setInterval('mdy()', 1000);
            ymd(); setInterval('ymd()', 1000);

    tstandard(); setInterval('tstandard()', 1000);
    tmilitary(); setInterval('tmilitary()', 1000);

}
```

And in my HTML, I'm doing:

```
<script>document.write($date.mdy + " - " + $time.standard);</script>
```

Comment: *OT:* Provide the `setInterval` (and `setTimeout`) function with references to the functions you want to call instead of strings that need to be parsed and evaluated. (It leads to unnecessary memory overhead and uglier code.) `setInterval(mdy, 1000)`

Comment: Umm. Yeah I did, that, now the error console is refreshing every second and the error count is going up every 1000 (the time I set in setInterval). So, apparently, I have 24 errors and counting...

Comment: Makes sense. You are calling both `ymd` and `mdy` while only creating a placeholder element for one of those (the same for the time). Comment out the `ymd()` and `tmilitary()` *lines* to see if it helps.

Comment: No, it didn't help. :( It's weird cause I did this on a separate computer and it worked perfectly, then I moved the files to another computer and now it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding two placeholder elements to the DOM – `<span id="ymd"></span>` and `<span id="tstandard">`.

Then, in the `window.onload` handler, you are trying to update contents of not only these two placeholders but also of two other elements which are not in the DOM (`id="ymd"` and `id="tmilitary"`). The `document.getElementById('ymd')` (and `'tmilitary'`) call correctly returns `undefined` because of that fact.

You want to remove the calls to the `ymd` and `tmilitary` functions.

```
window.onload = function(){
  mdy();
  setInterval(mdy, 1000);

  tstandard();
  setInterval(tstandard, 1000);
};
```

I also changed the calls to `setInterval` to simplify things. Passing references is more efficient and clear.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you actually get what is the problem, not only copying the code.

Comment: Yeah, I think I do. Usually with stuff like this I wont get it until hours after hours just staring at it. Lol.

Comment: Don't worry; it'll come with time and experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want this:

```
document.getElementById('mdy').innerHTML = string;
```

or this:

```
document.getElementById('mdy').nodeValue = string;
```

instead of this:

```
document.getElementById('mdy').firstChild.nodeValue = string;
```

That should take care of the errors. (There's no need to get the `firstChild` from a `getElementById` call, it already returns a node by default.)

Comment: Did you replace all the occurrences of the third line of code I posted? There were at least two in the code you showed us.

Comment: Yes, I did. I used the "Find and Replace" feature in my code editor then double checked it. I tried both ``.innerHTML`` and ``.nodeValue`` and still is showing the error. Could it be because of the placement of my code? Because I have some other stuff going on before the code I showed you but it has nothing to do with the features I'm currently working on.

Comment: You can't use the "Find and Replace" feature for that whole line--try something like searching for each occurrence of "`firstChild`" instead.

Comment: Okay, I did so. I had two other firstChild occurrences somewhere else on my core.js file but it didn't have anything to do with the date and time. (Which, by the way, I did delete the firstChild occurrences, but it's showing the same exact error in the same place).

Comment: Then one of your `getElementById` calls isn't returning a node. You need to find which line the error is occurring at (the Chrome debugger console can show you this) and find out if the code at that line is attempting to get access to an HTML node that does not actually exist.

Comment: You know, the error really seemed like this. And I thought we were on the right track, but apparently it was with the "universal body onload function" segment in my code.